# Get onclick string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, google-chrome, onclick

I had to extract the 2nd parameter (array) from an onclick attribute on an image, but jQuery just returned a function onclick and not its string value as expected. So I had to use a native method.
A quick search says it **may** work some browsers like FF, but not IE. I use Chrome.

```
<img src="path/pic.png" onclick="funcName(123456,[12,34,56,78,890]);" />
```

I thought this would work, but **it does not**:

```
var div = $('div_id');
var onclick_string = $(div).find('img').eq(0).attr('onclick');
var onclick_part = $(onclick_string).match(/funcName\([0-9]+,(\[.*\])/)[1]; // for some reason \d doesnt work (digit)
```

**This works**

```
var div = $('div_id');
var onclick_string = $(div).find('img')[0].getAttributeNode('onclick').value;
var onclick_part = $(onclick_string).match(/funcName\([0-9]+,(\[.*\])/)[1]; // for some reason \d doesnt work (digit)
```

Is there another way of getting the 2nd parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not store it in the data property?

```
<img src="path/pic.png" onclick="funcName(123456);" data-mydata='12,34,56,78,890' />

var div_data = $('div_id').data('mydata').split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I used the following code to loop through a collection of span tags and output their onclick strings. it's hacky but it works (firefox 7, JQuery 1.5.1). You can even override the string value.

```
$("span").each(function(index)
{
  alert( $(this)[0].attributes.onclick.nodeValue );
});
```